# Merge multiple AndroidManifest.xml files found as files, not inside libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have an Android project which for some various reasons might need to split the functionality of the single AndroidManifest.xml file into smaller files.

I know it is possible to merge these files specifically if they exist inside a dependency AAR file, where there are specific rules which dictate the actual preference. But since I only have one application, I would like to ask if there is a way to inform the build system that multiple **file** manifests are required to be merge.

Any idea if there is a methodology about it?

Comment: Per https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html, I wonder if you could create library modules that _only_ contain manifests, and then compose those manifests by including those modules in your main application?

Comment: This is possible, this is how we do it right now. I just thought if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inform build system to merge manifest files. If a dependent library has a manifest file, it's manifest is automatically merged into the app during build time.

Comment: As I said I don't ask for libraries but for free files. I know that libraries are merged automatically

Comment: Oh I don't think that's possible. You can try to add a blank module use its manifest and add that new module as a dependency in your app.